# How to broadcast message from one process in a communicator A to all processes of a communicator B in MPI using C language?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc, communicator

I am a beginner in parallel-processing, I want to send one value from a process belonging to communicator A to all processes in a communicator B , I tried to use the `MPI_Bcast()`, the process_sender should belong to Communicator B but it doesn't

```c
MPI_Bcast(&value ,value_size ,MPI_INT ,process_sender_rank, CommunicatorB);
```

how can I communicate between two separated communicators, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MPI processes can only communicate among processes within their communicator. From the [source](https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/introduction-to-groups-and-communicators/):

> Internally, MPI has to keep up with (among other things) two major
> parts of a communicator, the context (or ID) that differentiates one
> communicator from another and the group of processes contained by the
> communicator. **The context is what prevents an operation on one
> communicator from matching with a similar operation on another
> communicator**. MPI keeps an ID for each communicator internally to
> prevent the mixups.

In your case you can form a new communicator compose by the process A and the processes belonging to the communicator B. Lets call it CommunicatorC, then you can call the routine again but this time using the new communicator:

```
MPI_Bcast(&value ,value_size ,MPI_INT ,process_sender_rank, CommunicatorC);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured a solution it gives the desired results but I think it's not the best one,
first of all I sent data from **process_A** (belonging to **communicator_A**) to a **process_B** (belonging to **communicator_B**) using *point to point* communication (`MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()`) because they all belong to the `MPI_COMM_WORLD` communicator :

```c
/*to get rank of my process in MPI_COMM_WORLD*/
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);


/*point to point communication*/
if (world_rank == process_A_rank_in_comm_world_communicator)
  MPI_Send( &data ,size_of_data, MPI_INT, process_B_rank, tag ,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (world_rank == process_B_rank_in_comm_world_communicator)
  MPI_Recv( &data ,size_of_data, MPI_INT, process_A_rank, tag ,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &lStatus);
```

then I made the **process_B** to broadcast the received data to all processes in its communicator which is the **communicator_B**.

```c
/*broadCasting*/
MPI_Bcast(&data, size_of_data, MPI_INT, process_B_rank_in_communicator_B, communicator_B) ;
```